# Preserving data types when publishing to ArcGIS Online using ArcGIS Python API?

Tags: arcgis-online, pandas, arcgis-python-api

I have a Python script which does some data manipulation using Pandas dataframes, then outputs to CSV. The CSVs are then published to AGOL using the ArcGIS Python API, overwriting the existing services. This workflow is similiar to the one demonstrated [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/sample-notebooks/overwriting-feature-layers/#Overwrite-the-feature-layer):

```
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayerCollection
cities_flayer_collection = FeatureLayerCollection.fromitem(cities_item)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
cities_flayer_collection.manager.overwrite('data.csv') # data types in csv are unknown here
```

The problem I encounter is that occasionally some of the services fields have their data types changed upon publishing. Usually its a integer getting changed to a string, causing a breaking change to the application using the services.

It seems one approach to preserving the data types is to directly publish the data frame to ArcGIS Online (with column data types specified).

If this is not possible, is there another approach to preserving the datatypes when publishing?

My data consist of 3 non-spatial tables and 1 spatial table.